# Can't boot into Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

First of all, I'd like to say that I am a complete Linux newbie. I am trying to dual boot Linux and Windows 10. My Setup is:

- Ryzen 5600
- Gigabyte B450M DS3H V2 (BIOS version: F64)
- RTX 2060 Super (Driver version:
  546.29)
- 16GB DDR4 RAM
- 500GB M.2 NVMe (200GB Free)

SecureBoot is disabled in the BIOS. Windows Fast Startup is also turned off.

I downloaded "ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso" today and made my USB drive bootable (64GB, Newly Bought for this purpose) using Rufus with the GPT Partition Scheme.

When I boot from the USB, I get a few options:

> Try or install Ubuntu
>
> Ubuntu (safe graphics)
>
> OEM install
>
> ...

When I click the first option "Try or install Ubuntu". The Ubuntu logo shows up at the bottom with a loading animation, after a while the animation stops and I loop back to the boot menu with the same options. After a few failures, the system automatically boots into Windows.

Can someone please help? I am not at all familiar with Linux. I have been trying for the past few days to install following many tutorials and blog posts but none of them work. I even went to forum posts detailing fixes but those don't work as well.

I tried pressing 'e' on the 'Try or install Ubuntu' and wrote 'noveau.modeset=0' at the end of the Linux line as well but that too makes no difference.

Comment: Try pressing `F2` when the Ubuntu logo / animation displays. This will show more detailed logging so you can work out where it is failing (hopefully)

Comment: @moo It gets OK till 'Modem Manager' then it stops responding and loops back to the boot menu

Comment: Are there any error messages you can type into an internet search?

Comment: @moo https://imgur.com/a/RzPpCO9

Comment: Did you check your ISO? Can you ‘try Ubuntu’ in a different computer with that USB? I’ve never had any particular difficulties installing from USB so I’m a bit suspicious it’s a problem with the media you created.

Comment: @ayush I don't think those error messages are related. It's probably one of the last messages before it hangs that you need

Comment: Also check the media!! It's a good idea to do a checksum on the download and then again on the USB key to ensure it all copied over ok

Comment: Have you checked that you have latest firmware for both UEFI and SSDs? With nVidia, you need to boot with Safe Graphics and choose to install the optional restricted extras, so nVidia driver installed as part of install. Be sure to boot in UEFI mode to install in UEFI mode.

Comment: I had an old laptop which had legacy BIOS. I reformatted the USB to MBR, disabled secure boot in bios and Ubuntu live booted up just fine.

Comment: The laptop has an Intel processor with an iGPU but no dGPU.

Comment: @moo https://imgur.com/a/YMdZYTn these are the last few messages.

Comment: @ayush I have the same issue here. My PC has the same motherboard and GPU. I'm not able to install any Ubuntu version or flavors. I tried to use 2 different usb devices to put the iso, but the error is still happening. Any tips are welcome. Thank you

Comment: @RafaelTrojack hello! I finally fixed the error on my end. I have added the method as an answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem. Although I had disabled the secure boot, the keys had not been deleted. I had been frustrated for the longest time.

These steps are for the Gigabyte B450M DS3H motherboard. These steps may be different depending on the manufacturer and model of your motherboard.

- Have your bootable USB ready with your distro of choice. Ensure it is GPT partitioned for UEFI systems.
- Shut down your PC.
- Power it on.
- Repeatedly press **Delete** until you get into the UEFI BIOS.
- Now go to the **BIOS** tab.
- Disable **CSM support**. This will now show a few more options.
- Double-click **Secure Boot**. This will redirect you to a new page. You will see many options here.
- Now Double-click **Secure Boot**. Set it to **Disabled**.
- Now Double-click **Reset to Setup Mode**. This will clear the saved Keys and allow for problem-free booting.
- Override the boot order to put your USB at the top. Now Save the settings and you will be presented with a boot menu. Select the appropriate option as per your needs.